# data from the same source is displayed in the pivot header but not in the pivot item template

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am binding data to a pivot element in UWP. The data is displayed in the header template but the same header data when i try to display in the item template inside, it is not being shown. Why is this happening?? Also, the same data is being displayed in the item template outside the grid view.

```
  <Pivot x:Name="Pivot1" ItemsSource="{Binding Store_Product_x}" SelectionChanged="Pivot1_SelectionChanged">
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Course_Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Course_Header}"/>-->
                        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Store_Product_x}">
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Course_Header}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Pivot`, one `PivotHeader` corresponds one `PivotItem`. And in your code one `PivotItem` also corresponds one `GridView`. If the above code can run and meet your requirements, the `GridView` will only have one item under every `PivotItem`and value is same with `PivotHeader`, in that case why did we need the `GridView`?

For example, the itemsource `Store_Product_x` have two records and you bind to the `Pivot`. So the `Pivot` will have two items with headers shown. The first item is bind record 1 of `Store_Product_x`, and the second item is bind record 2 of `Store_Product_x`. At the same time, under every item you have a `GridView`. The first `GridView` has same source with first item which is record 1, how it bind `Store_Product_x` which contains record 1?

Please clear that the `PivotItem` to `GridViewItems` in your code is 1 to many relationship. Your above code is obviously wrong. Please reference the nested bind I mentioned in your previous thread.

If you cannot think out a right structure to meet your requirements you can consider change the control.